# How do I add a PKI certificate to a Go HTTP request?

Tags: go, pki

I'm trying to add a PKI certificate to an HTTP client, so that all requests made by it are authenticated to the services they are talking to.  I can instantiate an HTTP client by executing:

```
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        Proxy:                 http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            // TLS Implementation
        }
    }
}
```

This uses the default `RoundTripper` implementation, which includes a `TLS` configuration section.  However the TLS configuration appears to be shared between client and server.  Which of these settings do I need to add so that I can call other PKI services?

Comment: `Certificates` or `GetClientCertificate`, as documented: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that one only needs to add the `Certificates` attribute to the TLS configuration:

```
Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}
```

Where `cert` can be created using the helper function:

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(*certFile, *keyFile)
```

Where `certFile` and `keyFile` are two strings which point to `pem` files on disk.  As mentioned by Peter, you can also implement `GetClientCertificate`, but that is unnecessary for implementing PKI support.